# clean wipe data from laptop hard disk

Tags: hard-drive

I have to hand over laptop to another employee. I want to clean wipe it. So that my deleted files he should not recover using undelete software.

Please suggest.

I tried ccleaner but looks like it is just for removing junk files.

Any data recovery software should fail.

Is this possible?

diskwipe is deleteing all the data from my selected drive. what i wanted is ... i already deleted file which i do not want. i do not want new user to try undelete software and retrieve my deleted file.

Comment: [This is indeed possible](www.dban.org/).  We except some research to be done before asking a question.  Software recommendations questions are not on topic.

Comment: If you aren't worried about a recovery - just format it. If you are, then handing it over at all is a bad idea, and you should probably get that fellow employee sacked because you can't trust them.

Comment: This is not a software request.  The question seeks a solution to a problem and it does not necessarily require any additional software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give another try with CCleaner, have you checked for options 
[image]

and under Secutiy options, you have Very Complex Owervrite (35 passes). 
You can delete all non system partiton, and than delete all programs and files from C: drive and wipe free space.

But, if for some reason, tools like CCleaner are not good for you or you have trouble using them. You can do a very simple thing:
 Just copy paste some file until your disk is full. That will replace all deleted data with this new ones.

Here is a list of some similar tools like CCleaner for drive wipeing:

- http://www.diskwipe.org/
- http://www.hardwipe.com/
- http://www.dban.org/

And [here is some very updated web page](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/free-data-destruction-software.htm) (from march 2015) with some tools that you can use for data wipe.

Try to do some research for yourself, for example, take an 2gb USB*, or **create some smaller partition** to test these tools. Because, for example, CCleaner with 35 passes can take some time.
with these tools, than try to recover it. And see the results for your self. 
Weather you will use tools, or copy/paste files or some other idea. ;)

Also, if you have difficulties with C: drive, you can run [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) (or some other OS) from USB and format all your drives. 
There is an [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359540/securely-erase-hard-drive-using-the-disk-utility) and an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/359547/92577) on how to **[Securely erase hard drive using the Disk Utility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359540/securely-erase-hard-drive-using-the-disk-utility)**. 
Take your time, and figure out what is the best aproach for you.

- *as  **gronostaj** have said, this is not acctualy a god idea to test (or use) on USB and SSD drives, because their lifetime is limited by number of writes.*

Comment: This is a good answer overall, but these tools shouldn't be used on flash drives and SSDs because their lifetime is limited by number of writes and this procedure considerably affects it. Some USB flash drives can be low-level formatted with special tools (see http://flashboot.ru/iflash/) to minimize impact on their lifetime. SSDs on the other hand often come with hardware encryption and can be told to generate new encryption key, effectively making the drive unreadable without affecting its lifetime at all.

Comment: diskwipe is deleteing all the data from my selected drive. what i wanted is ... i already deleted file which i do not want. i do not want new user to try undelete software and retrieve my deleted file.